# python cant get loggin password script to work

Tags: python

I am learing to build a python script to check username and password from a text file and if correct logging the user. There will be two users and the file will have multiple users it.
I have got the script to work but I am having some problems with the password check. I wanted the function to loop back around it the password was input incorrectly. 
If I do this within the function to gets stuck in the same loop, I can only get it to work by comming out of the function and call it again

Below is the script that works. This will return 0,0 if the password is incorect and so the function is recalled.

```
user1Status = 0
user2Status = 0

def logging():
    filex = open('users.txt', 'r')
    x = filex.read()  # This will store the contents of the file as a string
    filex.close()
    login_info = x.split()
    numberUsers = (len(login_info))
    username = input("enter username")
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, numberUsers):
        if username != login_info[x]:
            count = count + 1
    if numberUsers == count:
        print('Username not recognised')
        return 0, 0
    password = input("enter password")
    for x in range(0, numberUsers):
        if username == login_info[x] and password == login_info[x + 1]:
            status = 1
            return username, status
        else:
            print('Your password is incorrect')
            #logging()
            return 0, 0

while 1:
    if user1Status == 0:
        print ('User1 please logging')
        username1, user1Status = logging()
    if user1Status == 1 and user2Status == 0:
        print('User2 please logging')
        username2, user2Status = logging()
    if (user1Status == 1) and (user2Status == 1):
        print("Welcome back %s and %s" % (username1, username2))#
```

If I comment out the return 0,0 and uncomment logging() at the end of the logging function it will keep looping around this function if an incorrect password is entered then a correct password. Is this something that cannot be down this way.

The reason I am trying to do it this was. I did not want to ask the user if they had an account again if the password was input incorrect.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `users.txt` would look like?  Is it a text file with `username password username password. . .` all on a single line? Looking at the way you've structured your code, this seems to be the case.  You may not have run into it yet, but one issue I can point out right away is that once both users are logged in, your program will print out the 'Welcome Back' message over and over, and you will need to kill it.

Comment: text file is username password each user is on a seperate line with only a space between the username and password. I understand what you mean by the welcome back part. I have more code for this I just cut it down for this post

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working using the following script. I have added an if statment to check the password. Thi is the full code

```
user1Status = 0
user2Status = 0

def logging():
    status = 0
    attempt = 0
    filex = open('users.txt', 'r')
    x = filex.read()  # This will store the contents of the file as a string
    filex.close()
    login_info = x.split()
    numberUsers = (len(login_info))
    username = input("enter username")
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, numberUsers):
        if username != login_info[x]:
            count = count + 1
    if numberUsers == count:
        print('Username not recognised')
        return 0, 0
    while (attempt!=3):
        password = input("enter password")
        for x in range(0, numberUsers):
            if username == login_info[x] and password == login_info[x + 1]:
                status = 1
        if status == 1:
            return username, status
        else:
            print("Password incorrect")
            attempt = attempt+1
        if (attempt == 3):
            print('you have used max attempts to enter password')
            return 0, 0

def register():
    username = input('Enter a user name: ')
    password = input('Enter a password: ')
    fw = open('users.txt', 'a')
    fw.write('\n')
    fw.write(username)
    fw.write(' ')
    fw.write(password)
    fw.close()
    return(username, 0)

def start():
    q1 = input("Do you have an account?")
    if q1.lower() == "yes":
        x, y = logging()
        return (x, y)
    if q1.lower() == "no":
        x, y = register()
        return (x, y)
    else:
        print ("please enter yes or no")
        return (0,0)

while 1:
    if user1Status == 0:
        print ('User1 please logging')
        username1, user1Status = start()
    if user1Status == 1 and user2Status == 0:
        print('User2 please logging')
        username2, user2Status = start()
    if (user1Status == 1) and (user2Status == 1):
        print("Welcome back %s and %s" % (username1, username2))
        print("")
        print("1: role dice")
        print("2: user1 Logout")
        print("3: user2 Logout")
        q2 = input("Select from one of the options above: ")
        if q2 == '2':
            print("User 1 has logged out")
            user1Status = 0
        if q2 == '3':
            print("User2 has logged out")
            user2Status = 0
```